# Find count in SQL using different set of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have below query to find the counts based on different date fields.

How can I get the result like below expected result?

The query shown is not returning the actual counts like the sample result.

```
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+
| WO_id | DateOpen  | DateFinish | DateClose | Location |
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+
|   100 | 16-Dec-18 | 18-Dec-18  | 19-Dec-18 | A        |
|   101 | 16-Dec-18 | 18-Dec-18  | 19-Dec-18 | A        |
|   102 | 17-Dec-18 | 19-Dec-18  | 20-Dec-18 | C        |
|   103 | 10-Dec-18 | 11-Dec-18  | 16-Dec-18 | D        |
|   104 | 17-Dec-18 | 19-Dec-18  | 18-Dec-18 | E        |
+-------+-----------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Query  (selection criteria : 16-Dec-2018 data only):

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DateOpen) AS Opened,
    COUNT(DateClose) AS closed,
    COUNT(DateFinish) AS finished, 
    Location
FROM
    JOB 
WHERE 
    JOB.DateOpen BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018')
    OR JOB.DateClose BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018')
    OR JOB.DateFinish BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018')
GROUP BY
    Location
```

Expected result:

```
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
| opened | finished | closed | Location |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
|      2 |        0 |      0 | A        |
|      0 |        0 |      1 | D        |
+--------+----------+--------+----------+
```

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You haven't asked one.

Comment: how i can get the result like in expected result

Comment: Be careful here. Those date strings cab interpreted differently based on your connections dateformat settings. Better to use the unambiguous ANSI compliant YYYYMMDD format for string literals.

Answer (score 2):

There is a trick you can with SUM and CASE, you use case to select 1 when it matches the criteria or 0 otherwise and then sum to "count" those items -- (since summing 0 or null is like not counting something).  Here is the codez:

```
SELECT
  SUM(CASE WHEN JOB.DateOpen   BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS opened,
  SUM(CASE WHEN JOB.DateFinish BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS finished,
  SUM(CASE WHEN JOB.DateClose  BETWEEN '12/16/2018' AND DATEADD(DAY, 1, '12/16/2018') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS closed,
  location
FROM JOB 
group by Location
```

Answer (score 2):

This should get you the results you're looking for. It only returns the rows that match the specific date criteria. The way you have your query currently built will result in it also pulling in rows that match 12/17/2018. You can test it here: https://rextester.com/MHT79618

```
DECLARE @SelectionDate DATETIME = '12/16/2018'

SELECT 
    SUM (CASE WHEN DateOpen  = @SelectionDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 end) as Opened
    ,SUM (CASE WHEN DateClose  = @SelectionDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)as closed
    ,SUM (CASE WHEN DateFinish  = @SelectionDate THEN 1 ELSE 0 end)as finished
    ,Location
FROM JOB 
    WHERE JOB.DateOpen = @SelectionDate
    or  JOB.DateClose = @SelectionDate
    or  JOB.DateFinish = @SelectionDate
group by Location
```

***edit*** damn, just saw Hogan answered while I was typing with basically the same answer.

Comment: :( sorry about that -- the same has happened to me too.  Giving you a +1 for the use of parameter :)

Comment: How to get the count by each date ?

Comment: I'm confused. Your question is very explicitly based on a single date. Are you saying you want counts for every possible date?

Answer (score 0):

In your original script, you count all rows and I think you might have the incorrect conditions. Please try following script.

```
create table JOB 
 (WO_id int, 
 DateOpen date,
 DateFinish date,
 DateClose date,
 Location varchar(20))
 insert into JOB values 
(100,'16-Dec-18','18-Dec-18','19-Dec-18','A'),
(101,'16-Dec-18','18-Dec-18','19-Dec-18','A'),
(102,'17-Dec-18','19-Dec-18','20-Dec-18','C'),
(103,'10-Dec-18','11-Dec-18','16-Dec-18','D'),
(104,'17-Dec-18','19-Dec-18','18-Dec-18','E')

;with cte as (
SELECT 
CASE WHEN DateOpen  = '12/16/2018' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as Opened,
CASE WHEN DateClose  = '12/16/2018' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as closed,
CASE WHEN DateFinish  = '12/16/2018' THEN 1 ELSE 0 end as finished,
Location
FROM JOB )
select sum(Opened) as Opened,sum(closed) as closed,sum(finished) as finished,Location 
from cte  
WHERE Opened <>0  or  closed<>0 or  finished <>0
group by Location
/*
Opened      closed      finished    Location
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------------
2           0           0           A
0           1           0           D
*/
```

Best Regards,

Rachel